# Magento can not connect GoDataFeed API through XMLRPC

Tags: xml-rpc, magento-1.9

I worked with Magento 1.9 and install GoDataFeed extension to import product from Magento.
I try to connect GoDataFeed with Magento through SOAP API:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/soap/api/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
```

and it connect successfully.

But when I connect through XMLRPC:

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://magentohost/api/xmlrpc/');
$session = $client->call('login', array('apiUser', 'apiKey'));
```

it returns error: 640: Method 'Login' does not exists and fault code 2: Access denied.

Both of 2 methods I use 1 account has been config user/role in system>Web services>SOAP/XML - RPC Users, SOAP/XML - RPC Roles.

In user setting in SOAP/XML - RPC Users, has item 'Current Admin Password'. Based on reaseach internet has shown: 'xml-rpc has some issues with non-ascii character sets.' So I want to ask if my current admin password contains non-ascii character, does it error connect occured?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is make sure to turn on logging and tail/check the logs on failure. Then of course I'd recommend reaching out to GoDataFeed tech support at 1-866-340-6619 ext. 3.

What's your store name in GoDataFeed? Maybe we can start looking and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you. I checked and detect error due to hhvm config. Now I don't know how to fix this error of hhvm.